# Can anyone see why my python regex search is only outputtings "0"s?

Tags: python, regex, file, python-3.x

I'm working on a python program to extract all the  tags within a kml file.

```
    import re

    KML = open('NYC_Tri-State_Area.kml','r')

    NYC_Coords = open('NYC_Coords.txt', 'w')

    coords = re.findall(r'<coordinates>+(.)+<\/coordinates>', KML.read())

    for coord in coords:
        NYC_Coords.write(str(coord) + "\n")

    KML.close()
    NYC_Coords.close()
```

I tested the regex on the file within [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) and it worked properly.

Here is a small sample of the kml file I'm reading: http://puu.sh/bhayn/2e233a1033.png

The output file contains lines with a single 0 on every line except the last one which is empty.

Comment: Aside: KML is an XML format, and so you can parse it using standard xml tools rather than working with regexps.  There are also handy libraries to make working with KML easier (e.g. [pyKML](https://pythonhosted.org/pykml/)).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have the `+` operators placed outside of your grouping.

So with `>+` this matches `>` literally between "one or more" times and using the dot `.` in conjuction with  a repeated capturing group `(.)+` only the last iteration will be captured, in this case `0` for each match result.

Remove the beginning `+` operator and move the one placed outside of the group to the inside.

```
coords = re.findall(r'<coordinates>(.+?)</coordinates>', KML.read())
```

**Note:** Use `+?` to prevent greediness, you also probably want to use the `s` (dotall) modifier here.